# jquery check this has content

Tags: jquery

How to check this has content in a jquery test? I want to check if each li is not empty, do some stuff.

[Online demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h8UXV/) And code repeart:

HTML

```
<ul>
 <li>list1</li>
 <li></li>
 <li>list3</il> 
 <li>list4</li>
 <li></li> 
</ul>
<div> </div>
```

javascript

```
$('ul li').click(function(){
   var list = $(this).html();
   if($(this':has(*)').length){
         $('div').html( list );
   }
});
```

CSS

```
ul{
    list-style:none;
    width:210px;
}
li{
    float:left;
    background:#ccc;
    width:200px;
    height:30px;
    margin:3px;
    display:block;
}
div{
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    line-height:30px;
    background:#ff0ff0;
    width:200px;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you're trying to do. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the size (length) of [`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/): http://jsfiddle.net/h8UXV/2/

I have slightly modified your code: You can eliminate the `$(this).html()` call when the content is empty.

```
$('ul li').click(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   if ($this.contents().length) {
         $('div').html( $this.html() );
   }
});
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `$this.is(':empty')`. This piece of code does the same thing as `.contents().length`, but might be slower though.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just check `list`, if it has something, it will be thought as true.

```
$('ul li').click(function(){
   var list = $(this).html();
   if(list){
         $('div').html( list );
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this jQuery:

```
$('li').click(function(){
   if($(this).html().length){
         $('div').html( $(this).html());
   }
});
```

Updated [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/h8UXV/1/)

Answer (score 0):

not tested but use the `empty:` selector

```
 if($("li:empty").length{
        $('div').html( list );
    });
```

http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/

Answer (score 0):

One approach:

```
$('ul li').click(function(){
    if (!this.childNodes.length){
        $(this).remove();
    }
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/h8UXV/3/).

Or:

```
$('ul li').click(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':empty')){
        $(this).remove();
    }
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/h8UXV/4/).

References:

- [`:empty` selector](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/)
- [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/).
- [`node.childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.childNodes).
- [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).